# Python: Average word length in a sentence with error checking

Tags: python

I have to create a program that calculates the average word length of a sentence. It must also prompt the user for a sentence until a period is entered, use a function that doesn't return any values to give the user instructions, and error check if there are no words.

So far this is what I have:

```
def main():
    print('This program calculates the average word length in a sentence!')
    s = input('Please enter a sentence: ')
    words = s.split()
    wordCount = len(words)
    sum = 0

    for w in words:
        ch = len(w)
        sum = sum + ch
        avg = float(sum)/float(wordCount)

    while True:
        x = input('Enter a period to stop:')
        if x == '.':
            break

    print('the average word length is ', avg)
main()
```

I've been smashing together other answers to this question online, trying to find a way to make this work. Please help. :( I'm only a beginner, so I'm sorry if this seems trivial. But I want to find out what I am doing wrong.

edit:

It is required that I use the while True loop and I must have the average word length of each individual sentence entered. 
To exit the program, a period must be entered. 
I need to have a way to check for errors if there is no word count.
If no values can be returned, I need it to loop back to the beginning.

Comment: Would you be able to add the Input, Expected output, and Actual output?

Answer (score 0):

Do you just need to divide by `wordCount` at the end?

```
average = sum / wordCount
print('the average word length is ', average)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a use for your `while True` loop involving `x` and a period, but I believe you want to output `float(sum)/float(wordCount)`.  Right now, you're just outputting the sum of all lengths.

Comment: I have to use that loop for my error checking :( But your advice on using float helped. I've updated the code in my question.

Comment: It is calculating the correct average, yes. But I still need it to be able to check for a zero average word length and display a message, and be able to loop back to the original prompt. And then be able to calculate the average word length of that sentence and NOT add it to the previous answer. 
Should I try a "try and except" clause?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you reorganize your program.  Make a function that asks the user for a sentence, computes the word count and prints the average.  Then, make another function that sets up a `while True:` loop; inside the loop, ask the user whether to continue.

This would give you "separation of concerns": the code to ask the user for a sentence will be together, and the code to ask over and over would be separate from it.

You could organize it even more: make a function that computes the average word length from a sentence, and then call that function from the user-input function.

P.S. Don't forget to handle the case where there are 0 words in a sentence.  If the user enters a zero-length sentence, I suggest you simply make the average word length be 0.

```
if wordCount != 0:
    avg = float(sum) / float(wordCount)
else:
    avg = 0
```

Comment: what if I used while avg! = 0:  ? Can I make an error for avg = 0 after that?

Comment: I put in example code to show what I mean.  Dividing by 0 is an error, so don't do the division when `wordCount` is 0.